# vc++ std::regex_match returning an extra empty string with an alternation regex

Tags: c++, regex

Why does this regex return an extra match of an empty string with std::regex_match?

```
std::regex trim_comments_spaces("^\\s*(?:(?:(.*?)\\s*[/]{2,}.*)|(?:(.*?)\\s*))$");
```

It seems to give the right matches, but I have to access the third element of the std::smatch results.<s>, which makes me suspicious that I got the alteration/grouping/capturing syntax slightly wrong.</s>

```
std::string trim_line(std::string current_line) {

    std::string trimmed_line = "";

    if (current_line != "#include <glsl.h>") {

        std::regex trim_comments_spaces("^\\s*(?:(?:(.*?)\\s*[/]{2,}.*)|(?:(.*?)\\s*))$");
        std::smatch sub_matches;

        if (std::regex_match(current_line, sub_matches, trim_comments_spaces)) {
            std::cout << sub_matches.size() << "\n";
            std::string sub_string = sub_matches[2].str();

            if (sub_string != "") {
                std::regex validate_line("^(?:(?:[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9\\s_+*\\-/=><&|^?:{().,[\\]]*[;{})])|[}])$");

                if (std::regex_match(sub_string.begin(), sub_string.end(), validate_line)) {
                    trimmed_line = sub_string;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Syntax error(2): " << sub_string << "\n";
                }           
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Syntax error(1): " << current_line << "\n";
        }
    }

    return trimmed_line;
}
```

Comment: What is the string you test it against?

Comment: Using it to parse glsl source code: `varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vTextureCoordinates;

uniform sampler2D uBaseTexture;
uniform sampler2D uHighlightTexture;

vec3 blend_material(vec3 k_diffuse, vec3 k_specular, float metallic, vec3 k_base) {
 // Semi-conductors are in the range 0.2 and 0.45
 float semi_conductor = smoothstep(0.2, 0.45, metallic); 
 ...
}`

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://regex101.com/r/dF2eO5/1)

Comment: Ok had tested it on there too, it seems to be only std::regex_match returning the extra match.

Comment: Without your code that we can check to repro the issue, we cannot help you. However, I think you are talking about 3 *groups* that you can access in the smatch object - and that is quite valid since you have 3: 0th - the whole match, 1st - `(.*?)` in `^\\s*(?:(?:(.*?)\\s*[/]{2,}.*)|` and 3rd - `(.*?)` in   `|(?:(.*?)\\s*))$`

Comment: Sorry it seems it was confusion on my part, I thought when there was the alteration in the regex that std::smatch would only get one of the sub-matches, not one match and an empty string for the other that was not matched, is that correct?

Comment: Whether or not a group matched, if you defined a `(....)` in the pattern, it will be initialized with an empty string first, then, it will either be populated with the captured value, or it will remain empty. Unless you are using identically named groups or branch reset, but you have no access to them in `std::regex`. Install Boost and use `"^\\s*(?|(?:(.*?)\\s*[/]{2,}.*)|(?:(.*?)\\s*))$"` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dF2eO5/2))

Comment: What if you concat groups 1 and 2? One of them will always be empty. Use `std::string sub_string = sub_matches[1].str() + sub_matches[2].str();`. See https://ideone.com/A5zJP2

Comment: Thanks that answers my question, which I've reworded to be clearer than what I was originally asking. Should the order of match_results be whichever capture starts first in the regex, in this example it seems to be always the third/last element. Will have to rework the code to be more robust or your suggestion would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex, once executed against a matching string, will fetch you a smatch object having 3 groups:

- 1) 0th group - the whole match,
- 2) 1st group - `(.*?)` in `^\\s*(?:(?:(.*?)\\s*[/]{2,}.*)|`
- 3) 2rd group - `(.*?)` in `(?:(.*?)\\s*))$`

Whether or not a group matched, if you defined a `(...)` in the pattern, it will be initialized with an empty string first, then, it will either be populated with the captured value, or it will remain empty. Of course, unless you are using identically named groups or branch reset, but you have no access to them in `std::regex`. You may use **Boost** and use `"^\\s*(?|(?:(.*?)\\s*[/]{2,}.*)|(?:(.*?)\\s*))$"` (see the `(?|` construct, and then all your needed values  will be in Group 1)

If you use your current code, you can concatenate groups 1 and 2 as one of them will always be empty.

```
std::string sub_string = sub_matches[1].str() + sub_matches[2].str();
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/A5zJP2)